# Computed fields facets are not working in Content Editor

Tags: sitecore-client, search-facet

I am on Sitecore 9 using SOLR.
We have added some facet configurations under `/sitecore/system/Settings/Buckets/Facets` to show them while searching for items in buckets.
While the facets for fields available on the template are working fine, faceting on computed field values isn't working as expected.
I see the computed field value available in SOLR.

In the facet settings item, I have added the field name from the index (all my facets vanished if i didnt add the _t for computed fields as opposed to template fields)

[image]

This is the search I am running on content editor

[image]

I got the solr query and ran the same:

[image]

[image]

While i get the same result count as content editor (24)

[image]

I see the facet values are also returned

[image]

But the facet isnt showing up in the content editor as indicated above.

Any ideas on what I am missing here?